# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) | undefined Symbol | Xcode React-native WidgetExtension

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I am trying to add Widget Extension in my react native project. When i try to build the project it is giving me two errors:

1. ld: warning: ignoring file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphonesimulator/libswiftUIKit.dylib': found architecture 'x86_64', required architecture 'arm64'
   ld: Undefined symbols:
2. SwiftUI._PaddingLayout>, SwiftUI._BackgroundStyleModifier<SwiftUI.BackgroundStyle>>> in ChargingActivity.o
   _swift_storeEnumTagSinglePayloadGeneric, referenced from:
   storeEnumTagSinglePayload value witness for ChargingActivityExtension.SimpleEntry in ChargingActivity.o
   storeEnumTagSinglePayload value witness for ChargingActivityExtension.ChargingActivityEntryView in ChargingActivity.o
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I wanted to build/run the project in xcode and wanted to integrate Live Activity in my app.